# Django - Return Two Attributes from a Model

Tags: python, django

How can I return two attributes from a model?

Vehicle Model

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Unit number for the vehicle")
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, validators=[MinLengthValidator(17)],  help_text="VIN of the vehicle", primary_key=True)
...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.unit
```

Appointment Model

```
class NewAppt(models.Model):
...
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    vin = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, related_name='VIN', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
...
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.vin = Vehicle.objects.get(unit=self.unit)
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

Whenever it gets returned, it returns just the unit number in the admin view.

If I change this:

```
self.vin = Vehicle.objects.get(unit=self.unit)
```

To this:

```
self.vin = self.unit.vin
```

Then I get this error:

> Cannot assign "'1XPTD4EXOCD128815'": "NewAppt.vin" must be a "Vehicle" instance.

Comment: Because `vin` in the 2nd model should be `Vehicle` instance. And `self.unit.vin` is a `CharField`. You should make the variable name and consistent and look at what is needed for you.

Comment: I do not see the point having the same Vehicle instance linked twice

Comment: self.vin = self.unit.vehicle.id you can use this